# Hibernate Criteria Query for many to many Enum

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a class Comment:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Constants.COMMENTS_TABLE)
@Audited
public class Comment {


@Column(name = "comment", nullable = false)
private String comment;

@ElementCollection(targetClass = CommentTopic.class)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.JOIN)
@CollectionTable(name = Constants.COMMENTS_TOPIC_JOIN_TABLE, joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "comment_id"))
@Column(name = "topic")
private Set<CommentTopic> commentTopics;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "comment_id", nullable = false)
private Long commentId;
}
```

Persisting the comment class works but the following criteria query:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Comment.class)
         .add(Restrictions.eq("commentTopics", topic));

List<Comment> entries = criteria.list();
```

throws org.hibernate.exception.DataException: No value specified for parameter 1.

This is the query built:

select this_.comment_id as comment1_0_0_, this_.comment as comment0_0_, commenttop2_.comment_id as comment1_0_2_, commenttop2_.topic as topic2_ from comments this_ left outer join comments_topic commenttop2_ on this_.comment_id=commenttop2_.comment_id where this_.comment_id=?

Am I using incorrect annotations?

Is the criteria query not being constructed properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I placed the CommentTopic enum in a CommentTopicWrapper class.

I updated the annotation for the commentTopicsSet to:

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = CommentTopicWrapper.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = Constants.COMMENTS_TOPIC_JOIN_TABLE, joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "comment_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "topic"))
private Set<CommentTopicWrapper> commentTopics;
```